# How to access a double pointer to an array in a structure with a pointer to the structure

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, structure

Header file:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifndef PARRAY_H
#define PARRAY_H

typedef struct patype *parray;

parray newParray(int lower,
                 int upper);  // returns a parray indexed with
                              // values in {lower,...,upper} where
                              // lower < upper; if lower is not less
                              // than upper print the warning message
                              // "Warning - illegal bounds for array\n"
// and return NULL
void freeParray(parray);  // frees up all of parray as needed

bool put(parray p, int i, void *item);  // equivalent to p[i] = item; does
                                        // bounds checking and does nothing
                                        // returning false if index is out
// of bounds, returns true if successful
void *get(parray p,
          int i);  // returns p[i] if index is in bounds of array;
                   // operation is undefined if index is out of bounds.
                   // Print "Warning - illegal index\n" if index is out of
// bounds.

int lb(parray);    // returns lower bound of array
int ub(parray);    // returns upper bound of array
int size(parray);  // returns size of array
```

C file:

```c
// Implimentation
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// void *vptr
typedef struct patype *parray;
typedef struct patype {
    int count;
    int upper;
    int lower;
    void **arr;
} patype;

parray newParray(int lower, int upper)  // creates the parray
{
    if (lower > upper) {
        printf("Warning - illegal bounds for array\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    void *data = malloc(sizeof(struct patype));

    ((patype *)data)->upper = upper;
    ((patype *)data)->lower = lower;
    ((patype *)data)->count = upper - lower;
    ((patype *)data)->arr = malloc(sizeof(void *) * upper + lower);

    return data;
}

int lb(parray p)  // returns lower bound
{
    return p->lower;
}

int ub(parray p)  // returns upper bound
{
    return p->upper;
}

int size(parray p)  // returns size
{
    return p->count;
}

bool put(parray p, int i, void *item)  // need to see if array at i is = to item
{
    for (k = 0; k < p->count; k++) {
        printf("%d\n", *(int *)p);

        if (p == item) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
// void *get(parray p, int i) //Need to return the actual array value if its in
// bounds but not working
//  {
// p[i] = i;
//  return p[i];
// }

void freeParray(parray p)  // frees memory
{
    free(p);
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "parray.h"
// Driver Code
int main(void) {
    parray pa;
    pa = newParray(5, 20);
    int *p1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    float *p2 = malloc(sizeof(float));
    char p3[20];
    put(pa, 5, p1);
    put(pa, 6, p2);
    put(pa, 7, p3);
    // get(pa,5);
    ub(pa);
    size(pa);
    lb(pa);
    printf("Lower Bounds %d\n", lb(pa));
    printf("Upper Bounds %d\n", ub(pa));
    // printf("%d",size(pa));
    printf("Check puts %d\n", put(pa, 7, p1));
    printf("Check puts %d\n", put(pa, 6, p2));
    printf("Check puts %d\n", put(pa, 7, p3));
    // printf("%d get\n",*(int*)get(pa,5));
    freeParray(pa);

    printf("(program compiled & ran)\n");
}
```

Need to access the arr in put and get but I have no idea how to.
I've tried the usual `p->arr` but I can't seem to get anything to work. But I just need to make functions put and get I've posted the driver code `parray.h` and the implementation file.
The project is basically just an array of void pointers but I don't know why its giving me such a rough time thank you sorry for the mistake earlier learning.

Comment: Please do not post code as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question. As a new user please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Okay im so sorry I think I fixed it I just edited it sorry

Comment: Don't hide pointers behind typedef. All you achieve with that is to make the code much harder to read.

Comment: bool put(parray p, int i, void *item) //need to see if array at i is = to item
{
if(i <= p->upper && i >= p->lower)
{
    
    p->arr[i - (p->lower)] = item;
    return true;
}
else
{

return false;
}

Comment: void *get(parray p, int i)
{ //Need to return the actual array value if its in bounds but not working
  if(i <= p->upper && i >= p->lower)
{   
return p->arr[i - (p->lower)];
}
else {
    printf("Warning - illegal index\n");
    return false;
}

}